# Python check if the texture is enabled

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

I'm not sure if this question is already answered. In the python, how can i know if that texture in a material is enabled or disabled?

I was planning to get all enabled textures not the disable ones.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know any name in python properties, you can find it in data-blocks outliner:

[image]

In your case the value named `use`

For example, this points to first texture slot of first material of selected object:

```
bpy.context.object.data.materials[0].texture_slots[0].use
```

Comment: Darn. I'm new to python but still i didn't know there's something like that. Thank you @Crantisz.